# apply window title to a GUI in python

Tags: python, gtk

When definging your own window, you can set the title when explicitly creating it:

```
class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="GCT")
```

Or if using an editor (I'm using glade), you can set the title at time of GUI design, under General settings > Title.

I'm trying to modify the title of the window in code from a loaded builder file, but the title isn't being applied. Instead it shows up with what is generated in the builder file.

```
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file("3x3.glade")
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)      
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("main_window")
    self.window.set_title="This is the new title"
    self.window.show()
```

Comment: Do you use GtkHeaderBar?

Comment: Not within the GUI builder, not knowingly. I'll investigate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `self.window.set_title="This is the new title"` is an assignment.

You're overwriting the variable that is pointing to the function that sets the window title.

Wheres what you really want is `self.window.set_title("This is the new title")` - a function call, to set the title to "This is the new title".

:)

Comment: you know, in many languages, this problem still hits me, is it a parameter to a function call, or a method/variable assignment? Not this this particular issue, but similar ones and especially when learning a new syntax/language.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the line from my builder file (generated by Glade):

```
<property name="title" translatable="yes">Dq Editor</property>
```

Here is the code right after reading the builder file:

```
self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
self.window.set_title("Hello")
```

Using Gtk 3.0 this worked in my program. That is, it changed the title from the builder (glade/xml) file. When the window came up the title was "Hello" which is different from the title in the builder file.